# Multiple conflicting contents for sourcemap source error when using client-only

Tags: nuxtjs3

I have a component that uses windows so I rendered it with client-only like:

```
<template>
  <h2>Testing Component2</h2>

  <client-only>
    <Component2></Component2>
  </client-only>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Component2 from './component-2'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    Component2
  },
  setup() {}
})
</script>
```

this works locally, the problem is that when I try to build to deploy, it always returns the error:

Multiple conflicting contents for sourcemap source error ./src/pages/index.vue

Is there a way to fix this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does it do that if built and run locally too? What happens inside of this component? Also, what is inside that file? This file should not be used as far as I know `src/index.vue`

Comment: @kissu the path is "./src/pages/index.vue" mb, if I run the project it works (yarn dev -o) and show a video iframe, the problem is when I try to build it to deploy it

Comment: Not in `dev`, but in `preview`. Not sure if you're using SSR or SSG, but try to run your thing in the same way as you do on production, but locally.

Comment: I am using firebase as preset, it doesn't support preview

Comment: What do you mean? You can either run Firebase's local functions or simply use a `serve/node` preview (since it's quite unrelated as of where you host it tbh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used
**LazyClientOnly**
and there add a lazy import for the component like: `Component2: () => import('./component-2')` and works perfectly